# Specify iteration in lmp (lmPerm pacakge in R)

Tags: r, iteration

I wonder if it is possible to specify an Exact iteration with lmp function in R. Here is an example with cars :

```
library(lmPerm) 
cars.slope<-lmp(cars[,2,]~cars[,1],na.action=na.exclude, maxIter=9999)
summary(cars.slope)
```

It's working good, but when I try it with my own data base, it's not working. It's always changing the number of iteration

```
cars.slope<-lmp(poppircv$ofid_mean~poppircv$mean.parent,na.action=na.exclude, maxIter=9999)
summary(cars.slope)
```

This is telling me that it's doing 5059 iteration and not the crazy and fix number of 9999 iteration that I want.

poppircv$ofid_mean is equal

```
c(0.13730,8.88790,13.56980,10.30080,12.34400,4.45670,0.20020,8.22860,2.35320,1.07580,0.11730,7.02940,13.16360,9.90550,10.36115,12.41320,0.63760,9.18390,14.90510,11.38160,5.58870,10.46680)
```

and poppircv$mean.parent is

```
c(10.3884,12.0500,16.9677,10.0315,5.5289,4.1219,7.8164,10.3927,0.1248,14.6878,0.5878,8.5014,13.4055,13.5698,1.3819,5.1349,8.3580,15.9249,23.2824,16.9287,3.2868,10.8343)
```

Do you have an idea of how I could fix the iteration to 9999?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set an exact value with any argument I 'm afraid but you can make it go to 9999 iterations with a different way:

As it says [here](http://plecor.eu.pn/PermutationLM.html) "This is because aovp() (same for lmp) doesn't calculate every possible permutation of data points. It keeps going with random draws until either a) it hits the maximum number of iterations (default 5000 iterations), or b) the standard error of the estimate of the P-value goes below a specified threshold (default 10% of P). "

But fortunately there is a way to affect the number of iterations:

According to the documentation there are 2 arguments that deal with iterations:

1. maxIter
   For Prob and SPR: The maximum number of iterations. Default 1000.
2. Ca
   For Prob: Stop iterations when estimated standard error of the estimated p is less than Ca*p. Default 0.1

So, you can be certain that you will reach 9999 by passing an arbitrarily very low number to Ca like 0.00000000000001.

Hope it helps!